# Emacs indentation support for C++11 syntax?

Tags: c++11, emacs

Now that C++11 is out, I wondered if there are any tips on improving indentation support in Emacs when more and more code is migrated from C++98 to C++11.

Examples:

- Parentheses are [often becoming braces](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/brace-brace/), which seem to confuse Emacs.
- [Lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd293603.aspx) are not well supported yet
- [Trailing type function declarations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Alternative_function_syntax) (cannot comment, as I have not used them)
- [Variadic templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_Templates) (though personally, I had no problem with them so far)

Here are some questionable indentions that I find myself working around:

```
struct m {
    int a;
    char b;
};

std::vector<m> foo { {1, 'a'},
        {2, 'b'},
            { 3, 'c'},
                { 4, 'd' }};
```

I'd prefer

```
std::vector<m> foo { {1, 'a'},
                     {2, 'b'},
                     { 3, 'c'},
                     { 4, 'd' }};
```

or even

```
std::vector<m> foo { {1, 'a'},
        {2, 'b'},
        { 3, 'c'},
        { 4, 'd' }};
```

for example.

Next one:

```
cout << 5
     << [](int a) {
    return 2 * a;
} (5);
```

I'd prefer

```
cout << 5
     << [](int a) {
            return 2 * a;
        } (5);
```

so that the block is indented relative to the lambda.

I find myself spending more time on indentation, which is annoying.

**Are any packages or customizations that help to indent modern C++11 code?**

(side note: I set up [clang-format](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) for Emacs, but I cannot get 100% compatibility which existing code and it also does not yet understand C++11 syntax very well. Still it is useful sometimes and sounds like a good idea for new projects.)

Comment: I also encountered a related issue [here](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14142/support-c11-syntax-in-c-mode). I wonder if you have found any solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Hot.PxL Not really. Migrating to clang-format is possibly the best approach.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking in the same way. Is there any way to suggest a number of initial indentation when I hit enter and creates a new line? Is `clang-format` only capable of indenting existing lines?

Comment: It would be helpful to see some concrete code examples that compare (a) how Emacs currently indents that code and (b) how you imagine it should be indented.

Comment: @Thomas Toby added some examples, which illustrate the problematic cases.

Answer (score 3):

I just manually installed the latest [CC Mode 5.33 from SourceForge](http://cc-mode.sourceforge.net/changes-533.php), which should cover most of what you are looking for:

> C++11 should now be fully supported, along with some features of C++14:
>
> - Uniform initialisation
> - Lambda functions
> - Parameter packs
> - Raw strings
> - Separators in integer literals
> - ">>" as a double template ender
> - etc.

Here are the indentations I get for your examples:

```
struct m {
  int a;
  char b;
};

std::vector<m> foo { {1, 'a'},
                     {2, 'b'},
                     { 3, 'c'},
                     { 4, 'd' }};
```

and

```
cout << 5
     << [](int a) {
          return 2 * a;
        } (5);
```

I also recommend installing `modern-c++-font-lock` (e.g. via [MELPA](http://melpa.org/#/modern-cpp-font-lock)) as suggested in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37469984/3233921).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [ClangFormat](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html#emacs-integration):

> ClangFormat describes a set of tools that are built on top of
>   LibFormat. It can support your workflow in a variety of ways including
>   a standalone tool and editor integrations.

It is integrated in emacs:

```
(load "<path-to-clang>/tools/clang-format/clang-format.el")
(global-set-key [C-M-tab] 'clang-format-region)
```

You have [many options](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) to define your indent style for C++11 and beyond.

> Clang-Format Style Options describes configurable formatting style
>   options supported by LibFormat and ClangFormat.

Few examples:

- `AlignTrailingComments`
- `AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations`
- etc.

Comment: While the link you provided may answer the question it is best to put the essential parts of your solution directly in your answer in case the page at the link expires in the future.

Comment: Actually, I am using ClangFormat (see my last paragraph). Over the time, it will understand modern syntax more and more.

Answer (score -3):

When I'm using emacs, the following setting is good enough for me to indent code:

```
; auto indent   
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq-default tab-width 2)

(define-key global-map (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)
(defun indent-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (indent-region (point-min) (point-max) nil)))
(global-set-key [f12] 'indent-buffer)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm not looking for to be rude.. but it doesn't answer the topic. The guy(like me) is looking for support all C++11 syntax and it doesn't, right?